# Crossbrowser XML manipulation and parse with XSL (Chrome, Firefoz and IE 8/11)

Tags: javascript, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I have a form where I get a `XML`, manipulate it as the user fill the form, and eventually transform this manipulated `XML` through a `XSL`. I need this solution to work in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 8 to 11 without compatibility mode.

I wrote a JSFiddle with the code I have working successfully to IE 9 (or at least without user complains), Chrome and Firefox. But I have an issue on IE 11. When my code tries to perform `transformNode` from `ActiveXObject`. I've tried some suggestions I've found in several sites, including here, but some simply doesn't worked or started throwing exceptions when my code tried to manipulate the `XML`. So I need help on getting this code working properly.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mfedatto/6nsc5bf1/

## HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

## JavaScript

```
try {
  function getXmlDom(content) {
    var xmlDom;

    if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
      trace.push("Creating DOMParser");

      xmlDom = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(content, "text/xml");

      trace.push("DOMParser created");
    }
    else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
      try {
        trace.push("Creating MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");

        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");

        trace.push("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0 created");
      }
      catch (ex) {
        trace.push("Creating Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        trace.push("Microsoft.XMLHTTP created");
      }

      xmlDom.async = "false";

      try { xmlDoc.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch (ex) { }

      trace.push("Loading XML content");

      xmlDom.loadXML(content);

      trace.push("XML content loaded");
    }
    else {
      throw new Error("No XML parser found");
    }

    return xmlDom;
  }

  function xslTransformTo(xsl, xml, wrapper) {
    if ((window.ActiveXObject) || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
      trace.push("Transforming with ActiveXObject");

      wrapper.innerHTML = xml.transformNode(xsl);

      trace.push("Transformed with ActiveXObject");
    }
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
      trace.push("Transforming with XSLTProcessor");

      xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

      wrapper.appendChild(xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document));

      trace.push("Transformed with XSLTProcessor");
    }
    else {
      throw new Error("No XSL parser found");
    }
  }

  function xmlString(xml) {
    return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);
  }

  function showError(ex) {
    var console = document.getElementById("console");

    showTrace();

    console.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ERROR!!! " + ex.message));
  }

  function showTrace() {
    var console = document.getElementById("console");

    for (var i = 0; i < trace.length; i++) {
      console.appendChild(document.createTextNode(trace[i]));
      console.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }

  var trace = [];
  var strXml = "<root>\n"
             + "  <fc>\n"
             + "    <sc>\n"
             + "      <i />\n"
             + "      <i />\n"
             + "      <i />\n"
             + "      <i />\n"
             + "    </sc>\n"
             + "  </fc>\n"
             + "</root>";

  trace.push("XML string defined");

  var strXsl = "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\n"
             + "  <xsl:template match=\"/root\">\n"
             + "    <ul>\n"
             + "      <xsl:for-each select=\"fc/sc/i\">\n"
             + "        <li>[<xsl:value-of select=\"position()\" />]</li>\n"
             + "      </xsl:for-each>\n"
             + "    </ul>\n"
             + "  </xsl:template>\n"
             + "</xsl:stylesheet>";

  trace.push("XSL string defined");

  var strWrapperId = "wrapper";

  trace.push("Parsing XML");

  var xmlDoc = getXmlDom(strXml);

  trace.push("XML parsed");
  trace.push("Parsing XSL");

  var xslDoc = getXmlDom(strXsl);

  trace.push("XML parsed");

  var domWrapper = document.getElementById(strWrapperId);
  var xmlItemList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("i");

  trace.push("All variables loaded");
  trace.push("Iterating item positions");

  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < xmlItemList.length; i++) {
      xmlItemList[i].setAttribute("p", i);
    }
  }
  catch (ex) {
    showError(ex);

    return;
  }

  trace.push("Itens positions iterared");
  trace.push("Transforming XML with XSL to wrapper");

  try {
    xslTransformTo(xslDoc, xmlDoc, domWrapper);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    showError(ex);

    return;
  }

  showTrace();
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.message);
}
```

P.S.: The only difference with the code I use is the trace and the `loadXML` based on string content, as in fact I use `load` method with a accessible `uri`.

### Edit 1 - 23/fev/16

I tried to run the `JSFiddle` posted by Martin Honnen on IE 11 and it shows `ERROR!!! No XSL parser found`. I did some refactoring using the instructions on MSDN page he suggested. That article instructs to try, not to test, because some plugins may be instantiated but not detected. And going that way my IE 11 creates and load my `XML` and `XSL` objects and content using `DOMParser` but fails to transform with both `transformNode` and `XSLTProcessor`. As done in: http://jsfiddle.net/mfedatto/6nsc5bf1/38

### Edit 2 - 25/fev/16

For some reason the solution doesn't work on JSFiddle, I'll do some digging about it. But with Martin Honnen answer I could load my external `XML` and `XSL` files crossbrowser, including IE 11. Here is the final code I used:

```
function loadXmlFile(path) {
    var xmlDoc;

    if (loadXmlFile.cache === undefined) {
        loadXmlFile.cache =  { };
    }

    if (loadXmlFile.cache[path] === undefined) {
        try {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0");
            }
            catch (e2) {
                xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xmlDoc.responseType = "application/xml";
            }
        }

        try {
            xmlDoc.open("GET", path, false);
            xmlDoc.send();

            loadXmlFile.cache[path] = xmlDoc.responseXML;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.load(path);

            loadXmlFile.cache[path] = xmlDoc;
        }
    }

    return loadXmlFile.cache[path];
}

function xslTransformTo(xsl, xml, wrapper) {
    if (typeof xml.transformNode != "undefined") {
        wrapper.innerHTML = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    }
    else if (typeof XSLTProcessor != "undefined") {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();

        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

        wrapper.appendChild(xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx, in IE 11 you need to use `new ActiveXObject('program.id')` inside of a try/catch, the check for the window property does not work.

Furthermore, the native IE DOM documents you create with DOMParser in IE do not support `transformNode`, so if you know you need an XML DOM document in IE to do XSLT transformation then you need to make sure you create an MSXML DOM document with `new ActiveXObject` and you need to do try to do that first in your code with try/catch, before you try to instantiate DOMParser.

So for the XML parsing from a string I would use

```
  function getXmlDom(content) {
    var xmlDom;
    try {
      xmlDom = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
      xmlDom.loadXML(content);
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
        xmlDom = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0');
        xmlDom.loadXML(content);
      }
      catch (e2) {
        xmlDom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(content, 'application/xml');
      }
    }

    return xmlDom;
  }
```

as done in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2016/test2016022301.html.

Comment: I tried to run your `JSFiddle` on IE 11 and it shows `ERROR!!! No XSL parser found`. I did some refactoring using the instructions on MSDN page you suggested. That article instructs to try, not to test, because some plugins may be instantiated but not detected. And going that way my IE 11 creates and load my `XML` and `XSL` objects and content using `DOMParser` but fails to transform with both `transformNode` and `XSLTProcessor`. As done in: https://jsfiddle.net/mfedatto/6nsc5bf1/38/

Comment: I have removed the link to the fiddle as it seems to serve up different content, I am not sure what is happening there (when I had posted the link I for sure had been working and doing the transformation in IE 11). I wrote http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2016/test2016022301.html based on the suggestion made above and it works fine here in IE 11, Firefox and Chrome.